# Uncaught Reference Error: Jquery is not defined - Woocommerce Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this error on my page and I believe it is what is keeping my add to cart button from working. What is supposed to happen is someone is to come to the page and choose which size shirt they want and then click on the add to cart option that displays afterwards. I can not get that to work and I know its a jQuery thing. Here is the code:

```
/*!
 * Variations Plugin
 */
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

$.fn.wc_variation_form = function () {

    $.fn.wc_variation_form.find_matching_variations = function( product_variations,     settings ) {
        var matching = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < product_variations.length; i++) {
            var variation = product_variations[i];
            var variation_id = variation.variation_id;

            if ( $.fn.wc_variation_form.variations_match( variation.attributes, settings ) ) {
                matching.push(variation);
            }
        }
        return matching;
    }

    $.fn.wc_variation_form.variations_match = function( attrs1, attrs2 ) {
        var match = true;
        for ( attr_name in attrs1 ) {
            var val1 = attrs1[ attr_name ];
            var val2 = attrs2[ attr_name ];
            if ( val1 !== undefined && val2 !== undefined && val1.length != 0 && val2.length != 0 && val1 != val2 ) {
                match = false;
            }
        }
        return match;
    }

    // Unbind any existing events
    this.unbind( 'check_variations update_variation_values found_variation' );
    this.find('.reset_variations').unbind( 'click' );
    this.find('.variations select').unbind( 'change focusin' );

    // Bind events
    $form = this

            // On clicking the reset variation button
            .on( 'click', '.reset_variations', function( event ) {

                $(this).closest('.variations_form').find('.variations select').val('').change();

                var $sku        = $(this).closest('.product').find('.sku');
                var $weight     = $(this).closest('.product').find('.product_weight');
                var $dimensions = $(this).closest('.product').find('.product_dimensions');

                if ( $sku.attr( 'data-o_sku' ) )
                    $sku.text( $sku.attr( 'data-o_sku' ) );

                if ( $weight.attr( 'data-o_weight' ) )
                    $weight.text( $weight.attr( 'data-o_weight' ) );

                if ( $dimensions.attr( 'data-o_dimensions' ) )
                    $dimensions.text( $dimensions.attr( 'data-o_dimensions' ) );

                return false;
            } )

            // Upon changing an option
            .on( 'change', '.variations select', function( event ) {

                $variation_form = $(this).closest('.variations_form');
                $variation_form.find('input[name=variation_id]').val('').change();

                $variation_form
                    .trigger( 'woocommerce_variation_select_change' )
                    .trigger( 'check_variations', [ '', false ] );

                $(this).blur();

                if( $().uniform && $.isFunction( $.uniform.update ) ) {
                    $.uniform.update();
                }

            } )

            // Upon gaining focus
            .on( 'focusin touchstart', '.variations select', function( event ) {

                $variation_form = $(this).closest('.variations_form');

                $variation_form
                    .trigger( 'woocommerce_variation_select_focusin' )
                    .trigger( 'check_variations', [ $(this).attr('name'), true ] );

            } )

            // Check variations
            .on( 'check_variations', function( event, exclude, focus ) {
                var all_set             = true;
                var any_set             = false;
                var showing_variation   = false;
                var current_settings    = {};
                var $variation_form     = $(this);
                var $reset_variations   = $variation_form.find('.reset_variations');

                $variation_form.find('.variations select').each( function() {

                    if ( $(this).val().length == 0 ) {
                        all_set = false;
                    } else {
                        any_set = true;
                    }

                    if ( exclude && $(this).attr('name') == exclude ) {

                        all_set = false;
                        current_settings[$(this).attr('name')] = '';

                    } else {

                        // Encode entities
                        value = $(this).val();

                        // Add to settings array
                        current_settings[ $(this).attr('name') ] = value;
                    }

                });

                var product_id          = parseInt( $variation_form.data( 'product_id' ) );
                var all_variations      = $variation_form.data( 'product_variations' )

                // Fallback to window property if not set - backwards compat
                if ( ! all_variations )
                    all_variations = window[ "product_variations" ][ product_id ];
                if ( ! all_variations )
                    all_variations = window[ "product_variations" ];
                if ( ! all_variations )
                    all_variations = window[ "product_variations_" + product_id ];

                var matching_variations = $.fn.wc_variation_form.find_matching_variations( all_variations, current_settings );

                if ( all_set ) {

                    var variation = matching_variations.shift();

                    if ( variation ) {

                        // Found - set ID
                        $variation_form
                            .find('input[name=variation_id]')
                            .val( variation.variation_id )
                            .change();

                        $variation_form.trigger( 'found_variation', [ variation ] );

                    } else {

                        // Nothing found - reset fields
                        $variation_form.find('.variations select').val('');

                        if ( ! focus )
                            $variation_form.trigger( 'reset_image' );

                        alert( woocommerce_params.i18n_no_matching_variations_text );

                    }

                } else {

                    $variation_form.trigger( 'update_variation_values', [ matching_variations ] );

                    if ( ! focus )
                        $variation_form.trigger( 'reset_image' );

                    if ( ! exclude ) {
                        $variation_form.find('.single_variation_wrap').slideUp('200');
                    }

                }

                if ( any_set ) {

                    if ( $reset_variations.css('visibility') == 'hidden' )
                        $reset_variations.css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn();

                } else {

                    $reset_variations.css('visibility','hidden');

                }

            } )

            // Reset product image
            .on( 'reset_image', function( event ) {

                var $product        = $(this).closest( '.product' );
                var $product_img    = $product.find( 'div.images img:eq(0)' );
                var $product_link   = $product.find( 'div.images a.zoom:eq(0)' );
                var o_src           = $product_img.attr('data-o_src');
                var o_title         = $product_img.attr('data-o_title');
                var o_alt           = $product_img.attr('data-o_alt');
                var o_href          = $product_link.attr('data-o_href');

                if ( o_src != undefined ) {
                    $product_img
                        .attr( 'src', o_src );
                }
                if ( o_href != undefined ) {
                    $product_link
                        .attr( 'href', o_href );
                }
                if ( o_title != undefined ) {
                    $product_img
                        .attr( 'title', o_title );
                    $product_link
                        .attr( 'title', o_title );
                }
                if ( o_alt != undefined ) {
                     $product_img
                        .attr( 'alt', o_alt );
                }
            } )

            // Disable option fields that are unavaiable for current set of attributes
            .on( 'update_variation_values', function( event, variations ) {

                $variation_form = $(this).closest('.variations_form');

                // Loop through selects and disable/enable options based on selections
                $variation_form.find('.variations select').each(function( index, el ) {

                    current_attr_select = $(el);

                    // Reset options
                    if ( ! current_attr_select.data( 'attribute_options' ) )
                        current_attr_select.data( 'attribute_options', current_attr_select.find('option:gt(0)').get() )

                    current_attr_select.find('option:gt(0)').remove();
                    current_attr_select.append( current_attr_select.data( 'attribute_options' ) );
                    current_attr_select.find('option:gt(0)').removeClass('active');

                    // Get name
                    var current_attr_name   = current_attr_select.attr('name');

                    // Loop through variations
                    for ( num in variations ) {

                        if ( typeof( variations[ num ] ) != "undefined" ) {

                            var attributes = variations[ num ].attributes;

                            for ( attr_name in attributes ) {

                                var attr_val = attributes[ attr_name ];

                                if ( attr_name == current_attr_name ) {

                                    if ( attr_val ) {

                                        // Decode entities
                                        attr_val = $("<div/>").html( attr_val ).text();

                                        // Add slashes
                                        attr_val = attr_val.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
                                        attr_val = attr_val.replace(/"/g, "\\\"");

                                        // Compare the meercat
                                        current_attr_select.find('option[value="' + attr_val + '"]').addClass('active');

                                    } else {

                                        current_attr_select.find('option:gt(0)').addClass('active');

                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    // Detach inactive
                    current_attr_select.find('option:gt(0):not(.active)').remove();

                });

                // Custom event for when variations have been updated
                $variation_form.trigger('woocommerce_update_variation_values');

            } )

            // Show single variation details (price, stock, image)
            .on( 'found_variation', function( event, variation ) {
                var $variation_form = $(this);

                var $product        = $(this).closest( '.product' );
                var $product_img    = $product.find( 'div.images img:eq(0)' );
                var $product_link   = $product.find( 'div.images a.zoom:eq(0)' );

                var o_src           = $product_img.attr('data-o_src');
                var o_title         = $product_img.attr('data-o_title');
                var o_alt           = $product_img.attr('data-o_alt');
                var o_href          = $product_link.attr('data-o_href');

                var variation_image = variation.image_src;
                var variation_link  = variation.image_link;
                var variation_title = variation.image_title;
                var variation_alt   = variation.image_alt;

                $variation_form.find('.variations_button').show();
                $variation_form.find('.single_variation').html( variation.price_html + variation.availability_html );

                if ( o_src == undefined ) {
                    o_src = ( ! $product_img.attr('src') ) ? '' : $product_img.attr('src');
                    $product_img.attr('data-o_src', o_src );
                }

                if ( o_href == undefined ) {
                    o_href = ( ! $product_link.attr('href') ) ? '' : $product_link.attr('href');
                    $product_link.attr('data-o_href', o_href );
                }

                if ( o_title == undefined ) {
                    o_title = ( ! $product_img.attr('title') ) ? '' : $product_img.attr('title');
                    $product_img.attr('data-o_title', o_title );
                }

                if ( o_alt == undefined ) {
                    o_alt = ( ! $product_img.attr('alt') ) ? '' : $product_img.attr('alt');
                    $product_img.attr('data-o_alt', o_alt );
                }

                if ( variation_image && variation_image.length > 1 ) {
                    $product_img
                        .attr( 'src', variation_image )
                        .attr( 'alt', variation_alt )
                        .attr( 'title', variation_title );
                    $product_link
                        .attr( 'href', variation_link )
                        .attr( 'title', variation_title );
                } else {
                    $product_img
                        .attr( 'src', o_src )
                        .attr( 'alt', o_alt )
                        .attr( 'title', o_title );
                    $product_link
                        .attr( 'href', o_href )
                        .attr( 'title', o_title );
                }

                var $single_variation_wrap = $variation_form.find('.single_variation_wrap');

                var $sku        = $product.find('.product_meta').find('.sku');
                var $weight     = $product.find('.product_weight');
                var $dimensions = $product.find('.product_dimensions');

                if ( ! $sku.attr( 'data-o_sku' ) )
                    $sku.attr( 'data-o_sku', $sku.text() );

                if ( ! $weight.attr( 'data-o_weight' ) )
                    $weight.attr( 'data-o_weight', $weight.text() );

                if ( ! $dimensions.attr( 'data-o_dimensions' ) )
                    $dimensions.attr( 'data-o_dimensions', $dimensions.text() );

                if ( variation.sku ) {
                    $sku.text( variation.sku );
                } else {
                    $sku.text( $sku.attr( 'data-o_sku' ) );
                }

                if ( variation.weight ) {
                    $weight.text( variation.weight );
                } else {
                    $weight.text( $weight.attr( 'data-o_weight' ) );
                }

                if ( variation.dimensions ) {
                    $dimensions.text( variation.dimensions );
                } else {
                    $dimensions.text( $dimensions.attr( 'data-o_dimensions' ) );
                }

                $single_variation_wrap.find('.quantity').show();

                if ( ! variation.is_in_stock && ! variation.backorders_allowed ) {
                    $variation_form.find('.variations_button').hide();
                }

                if ( variation.min_qty )
                    $single_variation_wrap.find('input[name=quantity]').attr( 'min', variation.min_qty ).val( variation.min_qty );
                else
                    $single_variation_wrap.find('input[name=quantity]').removeAttr('min');

                if ( variation.max_qty )
                    $single_variation_wrap.find('input[name=quantity]').attr('max', variation.max_qty);
                else
                    $single_variation_wrap.find('input[name=quantity]').removeAttr('max');

                if ( variation.is_sold_individually == 'yes' ) {
                    $single_variation_wrap.find('input[name=quantity]').val('1');
                    $single_variation_wrap.find('.quantity').hide();
                }

                $single_variation_wrap.slideDown('200').trigger( 'show_variation', [ variation ] );

            });

    $form.trigger('wc_variation_form');
    return $form;
};

$(function() {
    $('.variations_form').wc_variation_form();
    $('.variations_form .variations select').change();
});
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Where did you import jQuery?

Comment: numerous possible reasons ...jQuery library not being loaded in page, calling code before jQuery loads, `$.noConflict` being used eleswhere, conflict with another library using "$" alias. Not enough known for anyone to help

Comment: what else should I provide so that people can know what is wrong?

Comment: Did you add a `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` (or similar) to your page?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.variations_form').wc_variation_form();
        $('.variations_form .variations select').change();
    });
});
```

don't forget to include jquery library.

Comment: what do you mean by "don't forget to include jquery library? Sorry I am pretty ignorant when it comes to .js files

Comment: It seems you are more confident.It never means to say anything about your skills. Dear, don't take it otherwise. after all this is not good for you. try to concentrate on solving problem rather showing your skills by asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be incomplete, but the likely culprit is the script include for jQuery is after this code.

For example your HTML may look something like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script> ((function( $, window, document) {
        $(function() {
            console.log("hello world");
        }})(jquery, window, document); 
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

This would cause an error when attempting to use '$' inside the function would result in the error you're seeing.

Comment: Hello what does that mean?

Comment: Meaning that your code might look something like
`<html>
<head>
    <script>
        ((function ( $, window, document) {
            $(function() { console.log("hello world"); }
        })(jquery, window, document);
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>`

If you notice the script include for jQuery is after the JS that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, and not conflict in wordpress.

```
(function($) {
$('.variations_form').wc_variation_form();
    $('.variations_form .variations select').change();
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I tried this and I still get the same error on the line that reads

    `})(jQuery);`